# dash component Interval property n_intervals value shows differently in callback

Tags: callback, plotly, plotly-dash, intervals

I have this short code that use the dcc.Interval component to update a text in the callback, where I tried to print out the value of the n_intervals property.

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, Input, Output

app = Dash()

dccinterval = dcc.Interval(
    id='interval-component',
    interval=1000,
    n_intervals=0
)

app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        html.Div(id='live-update-text'),
        dccinterval
    ]
)


@app.callback(Output('live-update-text', 'children'),
              Input(dccinterval, 'n_intervals'))
def update_message(n):
    print('current interval in update_message: ', dccinterval.n_intervals)
    print('current n in update_message: ', n)
    return 'Message: ' + str(n)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8058)
```

Here is the output:

```
current interval in update_message:  0
current n in update_message:  0
current interval in update_message:  0
current n in update_message:  1
current interval in update_message:  0
current n in update_message:  2
current interval in update_message:  0
current n in update_message:  3
.
.
.
```

As you might see that the value of n_intervals got via the Input is changing correctly, but the value got directly from the interval component always stays at 0. I am wondering why. Can someone please help me with this? The reason I need to figure this out is that in my application when I tried to change the n_intervals’ value via component fails. That is, when I tried to set the value by doing `dccinterval.n_intervals = a number`, it does not work.

Thank you very much for any comments!

Answer (score 0):

`dccinterval.n_intervals` is showing up strangely because that's not the correct way to use the interval component. The other way, using `n`, which is the function argument representing the interval from the `Input`, is the correct way. However, you've defined your `Input` a bit incorrectly. Rather than referencing the variable for the component, which is `dccinterval`, you need to reference the `id` of that component, like this:

```py
Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals')
```

If you want to update the interval's value, you need to set up a callback that uses it as an `Output` like this:

```py
Output('interval-component', 'n_intervals')
```

and the function will `return` whichever value you want to update the interval to.

Edit:
So, the reason the wrong way doesn't work is because the variable you declare in the layout, `dccinterval` in this case, doesn't contain all of the details once the app is running. The callback function's argument, `n` in this case, has the right info because it has been updated through Dash. This is related to how Dash works, and how - more deeply - React works under the hood.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. However, if you look at the documentation here https://dash.plotly.com/basic-callbacks under the title "Passing Components Into Callbacks Instead of IDs", you will see that use `dccinterval` to refer to the component is eligible.

Comment: Ah, thanks for linking to that. I didn't realize that behavior was possible. Was my answer able to help you resolve your question otherwise?

Comment: I am sorry, but not really. I know the 'correct' way to do it, but what I really want to know is why the 'wrong' way does not work. After some reading, I guess it's due to the 'client side' vs 'server side' difference. Hopefully someone will come out and confirm that. Thank you very much though!

Comment: Added an edit with more details. Hopefully that is helpful.

Comment: Thank you again. It make sense. I don't know anything about React, maybe that's something I need to learn next. I originally thought the dccinterval variable works like a pointer, or reference in C. I guess it's not.